# How do I write and read the unstructured data in Hadoop-Singlenode server (E.x., image and video)?

Tags: hadoop, image-processing, video-processing, unstructured-loop, bigdata

How do I write and read the unstructured data in Hadoop-Singlenode server (image and video)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a mapreduce job with OpenCV. You can read more in this [paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1513/paper-14.pdf)